# Azure Table Storage - C# Server SDK - TableEntity vs EntityData and TableController vs ApiController(annotated with MobileAppController)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

We are in the process of using Azure Mobile App for providing offline-sync and push notifications support for our Android mobile app.

The sample project (TodoItem) that is provided for download uses `EntityData` and `TableController` as the way to implement.  `EntityData` doesn't have the notion of `PartitionKey` and `RowKey`.

`TableEntity` is the class that has the `PartitionKey` and `RowKey`.

When we are start using this to build our model instead of `EntityData`, we are asked to implement `ITableData` additionally - which means definition of properties including 'Id', 'Version', 'UpdatedAt', 'CreatedAt', 'PartitionKey' and 'RowKey'.

As a developer using BaaS, is it not too much to ask to implement all these things if we are to use `TableEntity`? Is there a way to use `EntityData` and still be able to specify the `PartitionKey` and `RowKey`?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your EntityData into DynamicTableEntity and use that when writing /reading from Azure Table Storage. While you do the DynamicTableEntity conversion you can assign the entity any Partition key and Row key you want.

If you are not familiar with how to do the conversion between you may look at this Nuget package: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObjectFlattenerRecomposer/

This takes any object and converts it to EntityProperty Dictionary, you can then set its PK and RK and create a Dynamic Table Entity.

I am also working with Azure team to integrate this API into the Azure Storage SDK:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/pull/337/files

**Usage:**

```
using ObjectFlattenerRecomposer;

//Flatten object and convert it to EntityProperty Dictionary    
Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> flattenedProperties = 
       EntityPropertyConverter.Flatten(complexObject);

// Create a DynamicTableEntity and set its PK and RK    
DynamicTableEntity dynamicTableEntity = new DynamicTableEntity(partitionKey, rowKey);

dynamicTableEntity.Properties = flattenedProperties;

// Write the DynamicTableEntity to Azure Table Storage using client SDK

//Read the entity back from AzureTableStorage as DynamicTableEntity using the same PK and RK

DynamicTableEntity entity = [Read from Azure using the PK and RK];

//Convert the DynamicTableEntity back to original complex object.
```

Imagine original complexObject was of type Order.

```
Order order = EntityPropertyConverter.ConvertBack<Order>(entity.Properties);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  We ended up using `StorageData` class - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/azure/microsoft.azure.mobile.server.storagedata.aspx which gives us the default mappings of fields that we needed while using a static structure for table as thats what needed.  Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. For conversion of simple business models into data model StorageData would work well, if in the future your Business Data Models get complex (more complex than what StorageData can handle in conversion) you may reconsider using ObjectFlattenerRecomposer API.